# ORA-00979 ORA-22818

Tags: oracle, ora-00979

Query works without the case statement. After I add the CASE statement,
Getting ORA-00979 (Not a GROUP BY expression) for the query below (because I did not add case statement to GROUP BY clause).
After I tried that (adding to Group By), I got ORA-22818 (Subquery expressions not allowed here). Any suggestions?

Note: All the left outer joins are to reference tables
Table: d_r_o og is the main DIM table.

The case statement is to return a timestamp condition for certain data criteria.

```
select nvl(country_name,'unknown_cntry') CNTRY_NAME, 
       nvl(rs.reg_tp_nm,'rgs_stus') RG_STUS,
       nvl(REBTN,'u_B_type') B_type_nm,
       decode(to_char(og.TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY'),
                '2015', 'CCCASE',
                        'CURRENT'),
       count(dkey),
       (CASE
          WHEN PG.rite_ts <= (SELECT pssd_dt
                                FROM lpyr
                                WHERE LPYR.PGY_KEY = OG.r_Pgy_KEY)
            THEN 'RECTIFIED'
          ELSE 'no'
        END) RCT_STUS,
  FROM d_r_o og
  left outer join LORSR rs
    on og.key = rs.key
  left outer join LRBR br
    on og.key = br.key
  left outer join LUST st
    on og.key = st.key
  group by nvl(country_name,'unknown_cntry') CNTRY_NAME, 
           nvl(rs.reg_tp_nm,'rgs_stus') RG_STUS,
           nvl(REBTN,'u_B_type') B_type_nm,
           decode(to_char(og.TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY'),
                    '2015', 'CCCASE',
                            'CURRENT'),
           count(dkey);
```

Comment: Not knowing your model, is there a reason that you don't join to 'lpyr' with all the other tables?  Then just compare the values in your case statement.

Comment: Please EDIT YOUR QUESTIOn and include the exact text of the error messages you're seeing. Thanks.

Comment: If you group by every result column, you might as well just remove the `group by` and add `distinct`. It would be shorter and easier to understand. Of course, perhaps you didn't mean to put `count(dkey)` in the `group by`, because having aggregate functions in a group by seems very counterproductive.

Comment: @ Justin Cave. LPYR is a reference table that defines program years.

Comment: @ Bob Jarvis - Done! Thanks.

Comment: Helli all. I've updated the question with more detail. Thanks for the feedback so far. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

For your  `ORA-22818` error, you should change this

```
 when PG.rite_ts <= (SELECT pssd_dt FROM lpyr WHERE LPYR.PGY_KEY = OG.r_Pgy_KEY)
```

Because **subquery expressions** `SELECT pssd_dt` may return many rows, not one value to compare with `PG.rite_ts`

One solution for this should be using [`min`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions087.htm) (or [`max`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions085.htm)?) function

```
when PG.rite_ts <= (SELECT min(pssd_dt) FROM lpyr WHERE LPYR.PGY_KEY = OG.r_Pgy_KEY)
```

Comment: Thanks Pham X. Tried that. Did not work. Same error.

Comment: Picture that if you comment out the entire case statement, the query is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input guys. I was able to figure it out using a little bit of each of the feedback from you.
I pretty much removed lpyr from the case and put it as another left outer join in the from statement.

Then i replaced the CASE statement with :
(CASE
          WHEN PG.rite_ts <= lpyr.pssd_dt
            THEN 'RECTIFIED'
          ELSE 'no'
END)

I also added this CASE statement to the Group by Clause and it worked. Thanks everyone. Whew!!! Results are accurate.